# My File On Server and Insert Data in Local System

Tags: php, mysql

My file on server like
http://www.example.com/insert.php

My code in insert.php

```
<?php
 $conn=mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","") or die("Unable to Connect");
    mysql_select_db("test") or die("Could not open the db");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (`uno`, `uname`) VALUES ('2', 'acv');");
?>
```

when i Enter open URL than i want to install my localhost database. 
How can i insert?

In php
Means My php file on server and i want to insert data in local system?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .change the host name.

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die("Unable to Connect");
 mysql_select_db("test") or die("Could not open the db");

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test`.`user` (`uno`, `uname`) VALUES (2 , 'acv');");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should better use mysqli functions, something like this should work.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO user('uno', 'uname') VALUES ('2', 'acv');";
$mysqli->query($query);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Obviously the table 'user' is already created in Database, if isn't you should create it first.

Comment: My php file on server and i want to insert data in local system?

Comment: 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' are the same, because the php file is on your server you are inserting data on your server.

Comment: You just need to mysqli functions (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).